# binding data in visual studio designer vs in code

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-binding

is binding data to a datagrid in visual studio from the designer more quicker to load data or a better more efficient way than binding data in code?

Comment: Probably not any difference in terms of performance. Using a designer rather than code is more a matter of personal choice - personally I would always use code, then I can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are no performance differences between the two. When you make a change with the designer, it changes your code.

Using a designer may be useful to begin but with time, I recommend you to stop using it because you are going to be sure of what you are doing and the designer can "hide" things.